# External List shows only BDC Identity

Tags: sharepoint-server, external-list, bdc

I have created an external list called Employees. When I go to site contents, I see Employees and when I click it, I see the exact contents I expect.

When I create a new page for my site and insert the web part for my external list in the designer, it just spins and spins.

And if I save the page and then display the page, my web part only shows one column and that's labeled as BDC Identity.

Does anyone know what I have wrong? Why can I see my data on the SharePoint default page, but can't use the web part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I traced your scenario on my side and actually, I got the same behavior.

[image]

**So I tried to do the following:**

- Edit the external list web part.
- At `Selected View` >  Select `New External Content Type` or any other view as shown below:

[image]

- Save your page, it should now show your columns.

[image]

- You can go back to select your appropriate view as you need.

**Note:**

You will face a loading issue after publishing your page.

[image]

So don't forget to check `Server Render` as shown below

[image]

**Important Note**

> If the retrieving items from LOB database are more than 2000 items you
> will face performance issue even if you increase its default
> max (2000 items) to absolute max (only 25.000 items) via PowerShell.
>
> For more details check [EXTERNAL LIST LIMITATIONS IN SHAREPOINT 2010/2013](https://blog.devoworx.net/2013/01/01/external-list-limitations-in-sharepoint/)